# Python sqlite how to grab variable of selected value

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this definition in my python script

```
def read_from_db():
    c.execute("SELECT title FROM book WHERE title LIKE 'Huckle%' ")

    for row in c.fetchall():
        print row
        title = row
```

I wanted to save the value of the title into another variable. but it seems that it doesn't work like that?

Comment: What exactly is the issue and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might just want to do `title = row[0]`. Row contains all column values of the particular row in the result set. Even if you select a single column you still need to index to get that value.